# Guarantee async js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

My head is about to explode. I can't figured out whether the code is async or not:

```
const fs = require('fs');

function Fn(file){
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if(fs.existsSync(file)){
         resolve('Yes');
      }else{
         reject('No');
      }
   });
}


Fn('file.txt')
.then(result => {
   console.log(result);
})
.catch(err => {
   console.log(err);
})
```

All the stuff is wrapped with `Promise`, so it should be asynchronous. But inside promise I have synchronous method `fs.existsSync`. 
Or it does not matter what's inside the promise, if it's promise - it's automatically asynchronous?

Comment: You might want to use `[fs.access](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_access_path_mode_callback)` instead, which also checks for file permissions and returns a promise by default. Otherwise you should resolve with No instead of rejecting, since the function has run succesfully and simply returns a result. When there is no error you should not reject the promise.

Answer (score 1):

`existsSync` is synchronous, but it takes some time to execute. Let's say, one second. So your promise will be resolved after one second, and since it's a promise, it's non-blocking. IMO, this is a way to make synchronous code non-blocking.

Answer (score 0):

As per my Knowledge given code is asynchronous. And yes it does not matter what's inside the promise .function `fn(File)` will always return a promise

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you put inside your `Promise` is synchronous, meaning that `resolve` will be called *after* `existsSync` finished. But `Fn` call *is* asynchronous meaning that any code placed after this call will be executed before the promise is resolved.

```js
function existsSync() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 999999999; i++); // Long synchronous operation
  return true;
}

function Fn(file) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (existsSync(file)) {
      resolve('Yes');
    } else {
      reject('No');
    }
  });
}


Fn('file.txt')
  .then(result => {
    console.log(result);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });

console.log('This will show before "Yes".');
```